# How to create a new pandas dataframe with multiple, custom index names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38236097/6735980), I am already able to create a new pandas dataframe with my own data and specified dtypes as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':pd.Series([1], dtype='str'),
                   'B':pd.Series([4], dtype='int'),
                   'C':pd.Series([7], dtype='float')})

print(df)
   A  B    C
0  1  4  7.0
```

However, what I need is to be able to additionally specify the index names when creating the dataframe. I suppose this should be done using the index arguments of `pd.DataFrame()` and/or `pd.Series()`, but I'm not sure in what way.

The **intended result** is that, if I print the `df` afterwards, I get:

```
             A  B    C
idx1  idx2
0     test   1  4  7.0
```

where `"idx1"` and `"idx2"` are index names, and `0` and `"test"` are the values that the first row in this (single-row) dataframe has for the two indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need define `MultiIndex` for each `Series`, e.g. by [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[0], ['test']], names=['idx1','idx2'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':pd.Series([1], dtype='str', index=mux),
                   'B':pd.Series([4], dtype='int', index=mux),
                   'C':pd.Series([7], dtype='float', index=mux)})

print(df)

           A  B    C
idx1 idx2           
0    test  1  4  7.0
```